# sound beep on mobiles like iphone: with javascript

Tags: iphone, audio, beep

Is this possible to make sound beep at mobiles like iPhone.....or play native sound....I testing phoneGap.js but it don't works to me......I want to make alert sound when new message arrives to end user at mobile...

Answer (score 0):

javascript sound.play worked for me last time i made an html/5/jss app, which if your using phonegap, must be.... app, was a simple html/js game.